# Element "jumps" after hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a set of Font-Awesome social media icons that expand and contract on hover. However, there's a problem when I stop hovering on each of the icons where the image in the middle of the icon "jumps" instead of smoothly collapsing like the rest of the icon. Here's the code:

```css
   body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Kreon', serif;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none; /* no underlines */
    }

    /*
    ** Rules for the flames in the footer
    */
    footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: #36454f; /* Charcoal gray */
    }

    .flame {
      bottom: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 50% 0% 50% 50%;
      background-color: orangered;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, yellow 15%, orange 25%, orangered 55%);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame:hover {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Position each flame icon, before and after hover */
    /* Each of the different icons should be 10px apart */
    #flame-facebook {
      left: -155px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }
    #flame-facebook:hover {
      left: -165px;
    }

    #flame-github {
      left: -80px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }
    #flame-github:hover {
      left: -90px;
    }

    #flame-linkedin {
      left: -5px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }
    #flame-linkedin:hover {
      left: -15px;
    }

    #flame-freecodecamp {
      left: 70px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }
    #flame-freecodecamp:hover {
      left: 60px;
    }

    /* Style the Font-Awesome social media icons */
    .fa {
      font-size: 20px;
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: rotate(75deg) skew(30deg, -30deg);
      color: white;
    }

    /* Move the actual icon down from the top to "center" it */
    .fa::before {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
    }

    .flame:hover .fa {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      transform: rotate(75deg) skew(30deg, -30deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame:hover .fa::before {
      top: 20px;
      transition: top 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="flame-facebook" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/travis.lannoye" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-github" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://github.com/tlannoye11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-linkedin" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/travis-lannoye-272a201b/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-freecodecamp" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/tlannoye11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

You can see the problem when you mouse over one of the flame icons, then mouse off it. A bit of research on similar issues suggested that the problem was with a border being added on hover, but I don't see how that applies as I'm not changing the border during the hover event...I think?

Comment: Hey, I am not able to replicate it: https://jsbin.com/vetutuzexa/1/edit

Comment: what do you mean when you say it jumps when you hover over it? i tested your code and it looks fine for me :/

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the problem is with the link elements inside the flame shapes. They were supposed to look like social media icons with the help of the Font Awesome library (hence the "fa" class names). See this pen here: https://codepen.io/tlannoye11/pen/pooMRje. Not sure how to include the Font Awesome library in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about with "jumping" here is the lag that sometimes occurs when hovering on the flame, at times it goes straight from the non-hover size to the hovered size with no transition.

This is caused by redeclaring `height` and `width`, which are more intensive tasks for the browser than using `transform: scale(1.2)`, for example.

The specific `left` declaration you were adding for each different type too causes a repaint and makes things lag, removing that stops the issue.

You'll want to tweak the exact values for your effect, as well as the `transform-origin` property (the rotating and scaling knocks this off), but something like this should get you on the right path.

*More info: [https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/_)*

**See further improvements below this code block if you can use flexbox.**

```css
   body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Kreon', serif;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none; /* no underlines */
    }

    /*
    ** Rules for the flames in the footer
    */
    footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: #36454f; /* Charcoal gray */
    }

    .flame {
      bottom: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 50% 0% 50% 50%;
      background-color: orangered;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, yellow 15%, orange 25%, orangered 55%);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame:hover {
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg) scale(1.2);
      transform-origin: bottom center;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Position each flame icon, before and after hover */
    /* Each of the different icons should be 10px apart */
    #flame-facebook {
      left: -155px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    #flame-github {
      left: -80px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    #flame-linkedin {
      left: -5px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    #flame-freecodecamp {
      left: 70px;
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    /* Style the Font-Awesome social media icons */
    .fa {
      font-size: 20px;
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: rotate(75deg) skew(30deg, -30deg);
      color: white;
    }

    /* Move the actual icon down from the top to "center" it */
    .fa::before {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
    }

    .flame:hover .fa {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      transform: rotate(75deg) skew(30deg, -30deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame:hover .fa::before {
      top: 20px;
      transition: top 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="flame-facebook" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/travis.lannoye" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-github" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://github.com/tlannoye11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-linkedin" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/travis-lannoye-272a201b/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-freecodecamp" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/tlannoye11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

### Further improvements: Using Flexbox instead of absolute positioning

If you can use flexbox, I'd avoid a lot of the absolute positioning you're doing here and refactor like so:

```css
   body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Kreon', serif;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none; /* no underlines */
    }

    /*
    ** Rules for the flames in the footer
    */
    footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #36454f; /* Charcoal gray */
    }

    .flame {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 50% 0% 50% 50%;
      background-color: orangered;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, yellow 15%, orange 25%, orangered 55%);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame:hover {
      transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg) scale(1.2);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Position each flame icon, before and after hover */
    /* Each of the different icons should be 10px apart */
    #flame-facebook {
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    #flame-github {
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    #flame-linkedin {
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    #flame-freecodecamp {
      transition: left 0.5s;
    }

    /* Style the Font-Awesome social media icons */
    .fa {
      font-size: 20px;
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: rotate(75deg) skew(30deg, -30deg);
      color: white;
    }

    /* Move the actual icon down from the top to "center" it */
    .fa::before {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
    }

    .flame:hover .fa {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      transform: rotate(75deg) skew(30deg, -30deg);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .flame:hover .fa::before {
      top: 20px;
      transition: top 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="flame-facebook" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/travis.lannoye" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-github" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://github.com/tlannoye11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-linkedin" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/travis-lannoye-272a201b/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="flame-freecodecamp" class="flame-wrapper">
    <div class="flame">
      <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/tlannoye11" target="_blank" class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```